# ¿Variable dentro de boton con onclick dinamico?

Tags: jquery, html

```
var variable = $.parseJSON(variable);

$('#tabla_servicios').append('<tr><td>'+variable.dato1+'</td><td>'+variable.dato2+'</td><td>'+variable.dato3+'</td><td><button onclick="EliminaServicio()" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Eliminar</button></td></td></tr>');
```

¿Cómo puedo ingresar? `variable.dato4` dentro del evento `onclick="EliminaServicio()`

Lo hago de esta forma  `onclick="EliminaServicio(variable.dato4)"` pero me lo interpreta como texto plano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías concatenar el valor, teniendo en cuenta que :

Sí es un número el `dato4` , la concatenación sería así

```
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td>'+variable.dato1+'</td><td>'+variable.dato2+'</td><td>'+
  variable.dato3+'</td><td><button onclick="EliminaServicio('+ variable.dato4+')" 
   class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Eliminar</button></td></td></tr>');
```

Sí el tipo de dato es una `cadena`, la concatenación sería así , notese las comillas `""` antes y después de la concatenación.

```
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td>'+variable.dato1+'</td><td>'+variable.dato2+'</td><td>'+
 variable.dato3+'</td><td><button onclick="EliminaServicio("'+variable.dato4+'")" 
  class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Eliminar</button></td></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias probar así:

```
onclick="EliminaServicio("+variable.dato4+")"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un poco de información de modo que el autor de la pregunta y futuros visitantes comprendan por qué propones esta solución? Sería genial que nos ayudaras a comprender cuál es el error y como tu respuesta lo soluciona.